# Using WP functions inside javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to use PHP variables inside a javascript function. What's a proper way to use a WP function like `get_current_user_id()` inside a script that get's enqueued via `wp_enqueue_script`? Right now I get this error

> Error:Call to undefined function...

**myscript.php**

```
<?php header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
?>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

         jQuery("#location option").each(function () {
             if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), locs) != -1) {
                 jQuery(this).prop('selected', true);
             };
         });

         if ( typeof jQuery.fn.chosen !== 'undefined' ){

         <?php 
         $userID=get_current_user_id();
            if($userID=='3') { 
             $max=6;
         } else {
            $max=3;
         }
         ?>
         jQuery("#location").chosen({ max_selected_options: "<?php echo $max; ?>"

          });        
    }


jQuery('select').each(function(index) {
            jQuery(this).chosen({
                disable_search_threshold: 1
            });
        })

    });
```

in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wordpress_scripts');
function wordpress_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'chosen', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/libraries/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chosen' );

    wp_register_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/myscript.php', array('jquery'),'',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
}
```

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: Why don't you enqueue your scripts conditionally?

Comment: Because of too many conditions. I guess `wp_localize_script` might be an idea?

Comment: What are those conditions? You shouldn't be trying to use WordPress APIs outside of WordPress using standard standalone PHP files

Answer (score 1):

I found out about `wp_localize_scripts` [here](http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/) and it solves my issue:

**functions.php**

```
$var=get_current_user_id();

$params = array(
  'max' => $var
);

wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'MyScriptParams', $params );
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
```

and in the `.js` file I can retrieve this variable with `MyScriptParams.max`.